# Rabbitmq preview message

Tags: rabbitmq

I have over 600 messages on my queue, and I want to take a glance at few of them (I dont want to delete them, just take a look). Which option should I choose? Of course I am thinking between:

- Nack message requeue true
- Reject message requeue true

What is the difference of them?

[image]

Comment: see https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation there should be no difference in this case.

> The AMQP 0-9-1 specification defines the basic.reject method that allows clients to reject individual, delivered messages, instructing the broker to either discard them or requeue them. Unfortunately, basic.reject provides no support for negatively acknowledging messages in bulk.
> To solve this, RabbitMQ supports the basic.nack method that provides all the functionality of basic.reject whilst also allowing for bulk processing of messages.

From: https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html